# Word for doing something because you want to

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I forgot the name of an adjective which means that you do something because you want to. It has a complete anytonym which sounds similar (I think they just have different prefixes) but means you do it because of outside factors. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

The word you are looking for is **intrinsic**, and its antonym is **extrinsic**:

> Intrinsic motivation involves doing something because it's personally rewarding to you. Extrinsic motivation involves doing something because you want to earn a reward or avoid punishment.
>   <sub>[Intrinsic and Extrinsic Motivation: What's the Difference?](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/intrinsic-and-extrinsic-motivation)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

***[voluntary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/voluntary)***

done, made, brought about, undertaken, etc., of one's own accord or by free choice

*His joining the army was voluntary, not because he was drafted.*

The opposite is "involuntary."